# Symfony 4 left join repository

Tags: symfony4

I'm new in symfony community, and i have a question for you !

I have 3 entities :

`Homework` with `id`, `title`, `description`

`Student` with `id`, `name`

`Note` with `id`, `note`, `homework_id`, `student_id`

In my twig view i want to display all Homework (order by title) and for each one show the note for student X (X is a controller argument) .

I try to do a `leftjoin` in Note to have all the homework even that for which he does not have a bd entry.

What the best way to do something like this ?

akro

*More informations*

- I try this, but i need to foreach twice in the twig view, i mean there is a better solution

  $homeworksRepo = $manager->getRepository(Homework::class);
  $homeworks= $homeworksRepo ->findByAll();

  $notesRepo = $manager->getRepository(Note::class);
  $notes= $notesRepo->findByStudent($student);

  return $this->render('vew.html.twig', [
      'homeworks'       => $homeworks,
      'notes'       => $notes,
      ]
  );
- I try with a queryBuilder, but i get only homework with a note in the result.
- I try with a queryBuilder and a leftjoin, in result a get something like this

  $res[0] => Homework Object 1
  $res[1] => Note Object 1
  $res[2] => Homework Object 2
  $res[3] => Null
  $res[4] => Homework Object 3
  $res[5] => Note Object 2
  $res[6] => Homework Object 4
  $res[7] => Null

  $qb = $manager->getRepository(Homework::class)->createQueryBuilder('h');

  $qb->leftJoin(Note::class,'n','WITH','n.homework = h.id')

  ->select(['h','n']);

  dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());

i would like to get

```
$res[0] => [Homework object1, Note object 1]
$res[1] => [Homework object2, NULL]
$res[2] => [Homework object3, Note object 2]
```

Comment: Note **entity** shouldn't have `homework_id` and `student_id` as property, but `homework` and `student`

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52829891/edit) your post and add the query builder ?

Comment: @Cid , I have homework and student in entitiy, i have write the db field name

Comment: *I try with a queryBuilder* Can you show the query builder? You only shown the result.

Comment: i dont have the original querybuilder... i rewrite one, now i have null element in the array if there is no note. in twig a can walk the array 2p2 , but i think there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your db structure your output should be the following if Home:Notes = 1:n :

```
0 => Homework => [
    Notes=> [
        0 => Note
    ]
],
1 => Homework => [
    Notes=> [
        0 => Note
    ]
],
```

Then your queryBuilder should look like:

```
$qb = $manager->getRepository(Homework::class)
      ->createQueryBuilder('h') // h is auto selected
      ->addSelect('n')
      ->leftJoin(Note::class,'n','WITH','n.homework = h.id');

dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());
```

With twig you can then go foreach(Homeworks as Homework) and beneath foreach(Homework->notes as note)